# 500 Internal Server Error returned after returning a view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view

I have this logErrors function which is supposed to return a view, along with the error messages, after it has logged the errors. The function works without returning the view:

```
public function logErrors(Request $request) : View
    {
        $logger = MYLogger::get('dsm');
        $logger->error('error', $request->all());
    }
```

However, when I want to return the view with the error message, I get a 500 error, and even the logging fails:

```
public function logErrors(Request $request) : View
    {
        $logger = MYLogger::get('dsm');
        $logger->error('error', $request->all());
        return view(
            'error.view',
            [
                'message' => $request->all(),
            ]
        );
    }
```

Any suggestions what can be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely permission problem that Laravel can not write to laravel.log file.

Comment: @Kyslik Surely that would mean the first piece of code would fail as well ????

Comment: Have you created separate class for logs? or you are doing this in controller?

Comment: I have a separate class for it

Comment: @RiggsFolly obviously we don't know; because it is not specified what `MYLogger` does, and "it has logged the errors" is ambiguous. For example Laravel can write to `/logs/abc.log` but can not create new file within `/logs` thus 500...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the storage folder permission by running the below command

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage    
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage
```